# age calculation method doesnt return the correct age?

Tags: java, android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I calculate someone's age in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116123/how-do-i-calculate-someones-age-in-java)

I want to calculate the  user age , and my method  doesnt give the correct age in case if the month of birth is equal to the current month and the day of birth  less than or equal the current day ( if the user enter his birth date through the date picker  as 9/4/1990  or 4/4/1990 the age will be 21 not 22) how i can solve this problem ? what is the update i should do to get the correct age in this  case ? please help me ....

**this is my method**

```
public static  String getAge(int year,int month,int day) {
    Calendar dob = Calendar.getInstance(); 
    Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();

    dob.set(year, month, day); 
    int age = today.get(Calendar.YEAR) - dob.get(Calendar.YEAR);

    if (today.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) < dob.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR)){
        age--; 
    }
    Integer ageInt = new Integer(age);
    String ageS = ageInt.toString();

    return ageS;  
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two problems with your code:

- if the date of birth is 9th April 1990, you need to write `dob.set(1990,3,9)` as months start at 0 ==> you probably need `dob.set(year, month - 1, day);`
- if the current year is a leap year and not the year of birth (or vice versa) and dates are after the 28/29 Feb, you will get 1 day difference on an identical date.

This seems to work but you should test it with various scenarios and make sure you are happy with the result:

```
public static String getAge(int year, int month, int day) {
    Calendar dob = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();


    dob.set(year, month - 1, day);

    int age = today.get(Calendar.YEAR) - dob.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    if (today.get(Calendar.MONTH) < dob.get(Calendar.MONTH)) {
        age--;
    } else if(today.get(Calendar.MONTH) == dob.get(Calendar.MONTH)) {
        if (today.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) < dob.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)) {
            age--;
        }
    }

    Integer ageInt = new Integer(age);
    String ageS = ageInt.toString();

    return ageS;

}
```

And a (very simplified) test:

```
public static void main(String[] args) { //today = 8 April 2012
    System.out.println(getAge(1990,3,7)); //22
    System.out.println(getAge(1990,3,8)); //22
    System.out.println(getAge(1990,3,9)); //22
    System.out.println(getAge(1990,4,7)); //22
    System.out.println(getAge(1990,4,8)); //22
    System.out.println(getAge(1990,4,9)); //21
    System.out.println(getAge(1990,5,7)); //21        
    System.out.println(getAge(1990,5,8)); //21        
    System.out.println(getAge(1990,5,9)); //21        
}
```

Comment: thanks, i will try the solution for the first problem , can you help me to solve the second problem? what i should add to the code?

Comment: See my edited answer with code

Answer (score -2):

You can compute the difference by transforming both dates in milliseconds and than in a Date object for example. Code would be something like this:

```
long ageMilis = today.getTimeInMillis() - dob.getTimeInMillis();
Date age = new Date(ageMilis);
return age.toString();
```

Comment: Are you sure about that?