# Java age calculator, not producing right age

Tags: java, calculator

Well as the title says.. I have a feeling I did something wrong in my code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class AgePrompt
{
    public static void main(String[] args){


        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

        String age;
        System.out.print("Enter your date of birth here: ");
        age = userInput.next();

        String myDate = 
        java.text.DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());


        System.out.println("Your age is: "+myDate);

    }
}
```

So where did I go wrong?

Comment: You do not do any calculations, but just get the current time and print it out.

Comment: ^ah okay.. makes sense.. my bad, so whats the correct code?

Comment: Read the javadoc of GregorianCalendar (and its superclass Calendar), and try to find out by yourself. Also, don't name "age" a variable storing a date of birth. Name it "dateOfBirth".

Comment: I guess, that's your task :) For a quick and dirty solution you might use the milliseconds to determine the age, if you want to do it right, I suggest having a look at the calendar classes.

Comment: I recommend that you use Joda. Here is an example of how to use it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116123/how-do-i-calculate-someones-age-in-java

Comment: You went wrong in two places: (a) Not reading the documentation, and (b) not searching Stackoverflow.com before posting. Your question has been asked and answered many times.

Answer (score 0):

You do not use `age` in further calculations and print out the result of the current date.