# How can I calculate the age in Java

Tags: java, sql, eclipse, oop

I have an Problem with calculating an Age..

```
public long getAlter() {

    Date now = new Date();
    long yearInMillis = 365 * 24 * 60 * 60  * 1000;
    long alter =   (now.getTime() - buildYear.getTime()) /365/24/60/60/1000 ;

    return alter;
}
```

- The buildYear is given: Year 22.05.2007.

--> (dd.mm.yyyy)

1. I need a function to calculate the Year (not the Month or so), in this example here: 7 Years.
2. I need a function to calculate the Days, in this example 2576 Days.

How can I define this?

Like this: 
http://www.topster.de/kalender/zeitrechner.php?styp=zeit&sdatum=22.05.2007&szeit=12%3A00%3A00&edatum=&ezeit=12%3A00%3A00&typ=jetzt&subDazu=%2B&jahredazu=0&tagedazu=0&zeitdazu=00%3A00%3A00

(already choosen)

@ALL: It's not an duplicate, because I will not work with Joda!

Comment: No, I will dont use Joda!

Comment: You're going to get a whole lot of rounding errors with `/365/24/60/60/1000`

Comment: @user3714925 Duplicate doesn't suggest only Joda. You can also use classes added in Java 8 or `Calendar` as shown in different answers in that question. BTW you are having problem with integer overflow in `365 * 24 * 60 * 60  * 1000`. To solve it use `long` as first argument of multiplying so rest of arguments will also be long like `365L * 24 * 60 * 60  * 1000`. Also you didn't specify if mechanism should include also time (hours, minutes). This detail is important since there will be no full day between `1.1.2001 12:00` and `2.1.2001 11:59` because you will lack one second.

Answer (score 3):

This link seems to have done something similar:

[How do I calculate someone's age in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116123/how-do-i-calculate-someones-age-in-java)

In case the link ever breaks, here is what is said:

> Check out Joda, which simplifies date/time calculations (Joda is also
>   the basis of the new standard Java date/time apis, so you'll be
>   learning a soon-to-be-standard API).
>
> EDIT: Java 8 will have something very similar and will be worth
>   checking out.
>
> e.g.
>
> ```
> LocalDate birthdate = new LocalDate (1970, 1, 20);
> LocalDate now = new LocalDate();
> Years age = Years.yearsBetween(birthdate, now);
> ```
>
> which is
>   as simple as you could want. The current Java stuff is (as you've
>   identified) somewhat unintuitive.

Comment: You mean the link within SO ?

Comment: @BrianAgnew yes - I doubt it will ever be broken, but in the rare case the question or answer is deleted.

Comment: @user3714925 - Why won't you use Joda ?