# need value from constructor that uses external method

Tags: java, method-call

In one of my constructors i have :

```
public Author(String firstName, String lastName, String middleName, int yearBorn, 
    int monthBorn, int dayBorn, int yearDied, int monthDied, int dayDied,
    String pseudonymFirstName, String pseudonymLastName, String pseudonymMiddleName ){
        name = new Name(firstName,lastName,middleName);
        born = new Date(yearBorn, monthBorn, dayBorn);
        died = new Date(yearDied, monthDied, dayDied);  

 if((pseudonymFirstName == null) && (pseudonymLastName == null) && (pseudonymMiddleName == null)){
            pseudonym = null;
        }else{
            pseudonym = new Name(pseudonymFirstName,pseudonymLastName,pseudonymMiddleName);
        }

    }
```

this constructor calls methods in other classes to store values for the `Author` class.

now i want to make a method that subtracts the value of `yearBorn` from the `current year` giving me the age of the Author

so far my methond looks like:

```
public int getAgeYearsOfAuthor(){

        return CURRENT_YEAR - (WHAT DO I PUT HERE?????);

}
```

how do i extract the `yearBorn` value (which is an int) form: `born = new Date(yearBorn, monthBorn, dayBorn);` in the constructor??

Comment: Are you sure that you want `CURRENT_YEAR` to be a constant?

Comment: Why don't you just calculate that in the constructor where you have the year as an int?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method

```
public int getAgeYearsOfAuthor(){
  return CURRENT_YEAR -(born.getYear)
}
```

but be careful if you use Date from JAVA it's constructor when you set year it  will add 1900 to you variable

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
LocalDate now = new LocalDate();
Years age = Years.yearsBetween(born, now);
```

[See the original answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116123/how-do-i-calculate-someones-age-in-java)

And make sure that your `born Date` is a correct `LocalDate()`

Answer (score 0):

In java8 you can do:

```
final LocalDate now = LocalDate.now();
final LocalDate birt = LocalDate.of(1980, Month.DECEMBER, 10);
final Period p = Period.between(birt, now);
System.out.println("You are " + p.getYears() + " years old.");
```