# Get age of person with Java ThreeTen BP

Tags: threetenbp

I would like to find the age of a person - given his birthdate (year, month, day).  How can I do this with ThreeTenBP?

EDIT:
One option I found is like this

```
    LocalDate birthdate = LocalDate.of(year, month, day);
    return (int) birthdate.until(LocalDate.now(), ChronoUnit.YEARS);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct in most countries. It assumes that people born on February 29 have their birthday on March 1 in non-leap years.
Read [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/February_29#Births).

Yet, this makes ThreeTen not consistent with itself, unlike Joda-time.

```
// if birthdate = LocalDate.of(2012, Month.FEBRUARY, 29);
System.out.println (birthdate.until(birthdate.plusYears(1), ChronoUnit.YEARS)); // display 0
```

If you want that getAge() to be symetric with plusYears(), you could write :

```
public static int getAge(LocalDate birthdate, LocalDate today)
{
  int age = today.getYears() - birthdate.getYears();
  if (birthdate.plusYears(age).isAfter(today))
      age--;
  return age;
}
```

See also : [How do I calculate someone's age in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116123/how-do-i-calculate-someones-age-in-java)