# LocalDate has private access in LocalDate

Tags: java

I am trying to find out someones age. I am following the answer given in here:
[How do I calculate someone's age in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116123/how-do-i-calculate-someones-age-in-java)

This is what I have so far:

```
public void setDOB(String day, String month, String year){

    LocalDate birthDate = new LocalDate(Integer.parseInt(year), Integer.parseInt(month), Integer.parseInt(day));
}
```

I am getting a an error when declaring the birthDate variable. I am getting the following error:

> LocalDate(int,int,int) has private access in LocalDate

.
I don't know what this error means but I am assuming its to do with data access *(e.g. private, public, etc)*

Comment: Your question is "I don't know what this error means but I am assuming its to do with data access (e.g. private, public etc)". I'm linking you to a post that explain in-depth the difference between those. Basically, you can't access a private constructor like that.

Comment: What puzzles me is: why is mi IDE showing me private constructors as method suggestions?

Answer (score 28):

The constructor you are calling is private.

You need to call

```
LocalDate birthDate = LocalDate.of(Integer.parseInt(year), Integer.parseInt(month), Integer.parseInt(day));
```

to construct your date.

Comment: `LocalDate.of` also accepts `int`, so it might feel more convenient to do `LocalDate birthDate = LocalDate.of(year, month, dayOfMonth)`.