# Could not find matching constructor for: java.time.LocalDate()

Tags: java, spring, grails, java-time

I am upgrading my application from `Grail 2.x` to `Grails 4.x`. As part of the process, I am converting my date/time references from `joda-time` to `java.time`. In doing so and when running my application, I get the following error:

```
  Could not find matching constructor for: java.time.LocalDate()
```

I have no clue how to solve this. I have read various posts that say I have to create a `converter` and other posts that say I need to add `Jackson jsr310` as a dependency in by `build.gradle`. However, a lot of what I have read were either for older versions of Grails or relate to some other programming language. Any insight/direction on how to solve this would be appreciated. Below is a snippet of the code that is causing the error.

```
import org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node.ParamsAction
import java.time.LocalTime
import java.time.LocalDate
import java.time.LocalDateTime
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
import com.app.torque.User


class DashboardController {

   def evaluationService
   def authService


   def index() {
       // Get User and Information
       User currentUser = User.read(session?.user?.id)
       Client userClient = Client.read(currentUser?.client?.id)
       Retailer userRetailer = Retailer.read(currentUser?.buyer?.id)

           ... //some additional code here deleted for conciseness


      dateList?.add(new LocalDate().getYear())


   }
}
```

Comment: Related: [LocalDate has private access in LocalDate \[duplicate\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35364532/localdate-has-private-access-in-localdate)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) doesnt have a public constructor

```
dateList?.add(LocalDate.now().getYear())
```