# Given a birth date, how can I calculate the current age?

Tags: java, date

`birthDate`'s type is `java.util.Date` .
What is the best way to calculate the current age?
I want a `java.util.Date` variable storing TODAY - `birthDate`.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you looked at how to obtain a date object with the current date? If you were not using a computer, what is the algorithm you would use?

Comment: A `java.util.Date` represents a moment on the timeline. So by definition it cannot represent a span of elapsed time. So your request is impossible. Instead, look at the java.time framework, in particular the [`Period`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Period.html) class.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on what do you mean by current age.

If you mean the precise astronomical meaning, use

```
DateTime startDate = new DateTime(2000, 1, 19, 5, 14, 0, 0);
DateTime endDate = new DateTime();
Days d = Days.daysBetween(startDate, endDate);
```

If you need the common sense difference, based on both dates given in whole days:

```
long thisDay = (new Date()).getTime() / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);

DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy");
Date birthDate = formatter.parse("11-June-07");

long birthdayInDays = birthDate.getTime() / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
long dayDiff = thisDay - birthdayInDays;
```

Comment: tnx, but how can I go from this (`dayDiff`, or `d`), to a variable of type Date?

Comment: Take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116123/how-do-i-calculate-someones-age-in-java

Comment: @David, difference of dates is NOT a date itself. A date, for example, has leap years. Difference of dates hasn't it.