# How to enable auto delete of 0 in day and month in a date

Tags: java, android, date

I would like to create an age calculator in a register form without Joda Time, but I have a problem with concatenating an int. It deletes the 0 from the day component (by example 04) and month component, so it completely miscalculates the age. I tried to put it first in a `String` then into an `int`, but that doesn't work.

```
private void setAge(View view) {

    Calendar calendarB = Calendar.getInstance();
    int years = calendarB.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = calendarB.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = calendarB.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    //int
    currentDate = Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(years) + String.valueOf(month + 1) + String.valueOf(day));

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            //int
            birthDate = Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(year) + String.valueOf(monthOfYear + 1) + String.valueOf(dayOfMonth));

            ageI = (currentDate - birthDate) / 10000;

            String age = Integer.toString(ageI);
            birth.setText(age);

            datePickerDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }, calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
}
```

Comment: Without Joda? Why? Which API level are you targeting anyway?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I calculate someone's age in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116123/how-do-i-calculate-someones-age-in-java)

Comment: first, get age by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116123/how-do-i-calculate-someones-age-in-java), and then from that `int age` result, format it to `String` like "99", "09" and set back

Comment: @MCEmperor : I would like to target all API, with one setage in Joda and one in Calendar but I'm a newbie, it's not usefull ?

Comment: Well, using `Calendar` [is wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969442/whats-wrong-with-java-date-time-api) nowadays. You should use the new Java Date and Time API (in the `java.time` package). If you need to target API levels below 26, then you could use the [ThreeTen Backport](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/). Juggling with integers to calculate an age is not the way to do it. The question linked by DangNguyen provides a simple solution: `Period.between(birthDate, currentDate).getYears()`.

Comment: I don't find how to have "birthdate" and currentdate" in this example.
My phone have API 23, thanks for links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Integer` always remove preceding 0 from a value. Use this method/function to convert `Int` to `String` with preceding 0.

```
 // ADDS 0  e.g - 02 instead of 2
    public String checkDigit (int number) {
        return number <= 9 ? "0" + number : String.valueOf(number);
    }
```

**EDIT**

In your case, just use these lines

```
private void setAge(View view) {

Calendar calendarB = Calendar.getInstance();
int years = calendarB.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int month = calendarB.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int day = calendarB.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
//int
currentDate = Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(years) + String.valueOf(month + 1) + String.valueOf(day));

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar dob = Calendar.getInstance();

datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        //int
        birthDate = Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(year) + String.valueOf(monthOfYear + 1) + String.valueOf(dayOfMonth));

        // New code
        dob.set(year, month, day); 
        int age = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) - dob.get(Calendar.YEAR);

        if (calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) < dob.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR)){
            age--; 
        }

        String age = checkDigit(age);
        birth.setText(age);

        datePickerDialog.dismiss();
    }
}, calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
}
```

Comment: If you have String "04" and you convert it in integer the it will always remove preceding 0. `Integer.valueOf()` is never return preceding 0. The method `checkDigit()` always convert integer to string with preceding 0. but if you again parse the string in integer using `Integer.valueOf()` then it will remove the 0.

Comment: Easy, please, @user392117. I recommend waiting a couple of days before accepting an answer since questions without an accepted answer tend to get more attention, so to allow more answers to roll in before picking the one to accept. I agree that accepting an answer in the end is good style.

Answer (score 1):

Well, juggling like this with integers to calculate an age is not the way to do it.

First, using the `Calendar` class [is wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969442/whats-wrong-with-java-date-time-api) nowadays. You should use the [new Java Date and Time API](https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-date-time-intro) (in the `java.time` package). The `between` method of the `Period` class seemlessly calculates the difference between those two years:

```
Period.between(birthDate, currentDate);
```

You can then call `getYears` to get the years. It takes advantage of the fact that when we humans say our age, we do not round the value at all. For example, if I turn 30 tomorrow, I'm today still 29 years old.

This should work:

```
final LocalDate now = LocalDate.now();
datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        LocalDate birthDate = LocalDate.of(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
        int age = Period.between(birthDate, now).getYears();
        birth.setText(String.valueOf(age));

        datePickerDialog.dismiss();
    }
}, now.getYear(), now.getMonthValue(), now.getDayOfMonth());
```

---

<sup>*If you need to target API levels below 26, then you could use the [ThreeTen ABP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), which backports the Java 8 Date and Time functionality.*</sup>

Comment: Thanks ! I will search how to use ThreeTen ABP now, if you have others good link on that I will take it with pleasure. In any case thank you very much for your complete and illumating answer !