# Difference between two dates not working properly?

Tags: android, datetime, kotlin, android-date

I am trying to find if selected `date` and today's `date` difference is equal to or greater than 18 years or not.

For getting today's date following is my code

```
private val simpleDateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.getDefault())
    private val date = Date()
    private val todayDate = simpleDateFormat.parse(simpleDateFormat.format(date)).time
private val cal = Calendar.getInstance()

 cal.time = date
 val date = simpleDateFormat.parse("12-11-2001").time
val years = (todayDate - date) / (1000L * 60 * 60 * 24 * cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR))
```

Now my selected date is 12-11-2001 and todays date is 11-11-2019 so it should show 17 years but it show 18 years. Even if I select 13,14 or 15th November 2001, it shows 18 years instead of 17 years but if I select 16th Novemeber 2001 then it shows 17 years. I am not able to understand why this behaviour happen.

Comment: `private val todayDate = simpleDateFormat.parse(simpleDateFormat.format(date))` what a strange line. It does actually nothing. Use `date` instead of it all.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko Thank you for optimising my code but still facing the same issue

Comment: I think you need to use `DatePickerDialog` it will easily implemented according to your requirements.

Comment: I am using DatePickerDialog when user is selecting the date. Just for convenience in my question I have hardcoded the selected date @ParthLotia

Comment: You need condition like if user is above 18 years old or not?

Comment: @ParthLotia Yeah I need to check if user is 18 or greater than 18

Comment: @GoFudgeYourSelves I edited my answer please check.

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: Related and inspirational: [How do I calculate someone's age in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116123/how-do-i-calculate-someones-age-in-java)

Comment: I cannot reproduce. I get the opposite problem. Your code yieds 18, and even if I parse `15-11-2001` instead, it still yields 18 (today is November 11 here).

Answer (score 1):

Better to use `java.time` API for this kind of tasks:

```
import java.time.*
import java.time.format.*
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit

fun main() {
    val today = LocalDate.now()
    val date = LocalDate.parse("12-11-2001", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy"))

    val diff = ChronoUnit.YEARS.between(date, today)

    println("Diff between $date and $today is $diff years")
}
```

If you can't use `java.time` yet due to minSdkVersion restriction, you can use [ThreeTen Backport](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project and its Android adaptation [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

Answer (score 0):

- Try this might help you .

  ```
  context  = YourActivity.this;
  btn_datePicker = findViewById(R.id.btn_datePicker);

  Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
  final int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
  final int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
  final int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);

  btn_datePicker.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
          datePicker = new DatePickerDialog(context, new   DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
              @Override
              public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                  if (i > year - 18 && i1 + 1 > month - (12 * 18)) {


                      Toast.makeText(context, "Select Proper birth date", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                  } else {
                      Toast.makeText(context, ""+i2 + "/" + (i1 + 1) + "/" + i, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  }


              }
          }, year, month, day);
          datePicker.show();
      }
  });
  ```

Comment: Format your date according to your requirement in `yourtextview.setText`

Comment: Does not work. I don't think there is an issue in setting the date. The problem is in the difference between todays and selected date

Comment: I don't know it is working for me also I edit my answer please check.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Import all component as shown in Image.]**Here is the Proper Solution to get number of years between two dates (Difference between Two dates).**

**Add this code in onCreate Method.**

```
var d1: Date? = null
var d2: Date? = null
val dateStart = "12-11-2001"
val dateStop = "11-11-2019"
val format = SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy")
d1 = format.parse(dateStart)
d2 = format.parse(dateStop)
Log.d("Year_Difference", getDiffYears(d1, d2).toString())
```

**Add this two method in your activity.**

```
fun getDiffYears(first: Date, last: Date): Int {
        val a = getCalendar(first)
        val b = getCalendar(last)
        var diff = b.get(YEAR) - a.get(YEAR)
        if (a.get(MONTH) > b.get(MONTH) || a.get(MONTH) == b.get(MONTH) && a.get(DATE) > b.get(DATE)) {
            diff--
        }
        return diff
    }


fun getCalendar(date: Date): Calendar {
        val cal = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.US)
        cal.time = date
        return cal
    }
```

Comment: I think you haven't Import MONTH properly in my case it's working properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
public int GetDifference(long start,long end){
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTimeInMillis(start);
    int hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int min = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    long t=(23-hour)*3600000+(59-min)*60000;

    t=start+t;

    int diff=0;
    if(end>t){
        diff=(int)((end-t)/ TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(1))+1;
    }

    int leapYear = (diff/365)/4;


    return  (diff-leapYear)/365;
}
```

you need to define leap years, this code returns 17